TinyMCE use undo to restore deleted text
I'm using TineMCE@5.10.3 and React@18.2
I've encountered an unwanted behavior in Tiny where when you delete characters, the action isn't saved in the undoManager stack, and if you try to undo, it deletes the last section written instead of restoring the deleted characters.

What I expected: The undo button would restore the text that I just deleted

What actually happened: The whole section of text that I was writing was deleted by the undo, and there is no way (undo/redo) to restore the text deleted by hitting backspace


How I've tried to fix this:

I've tried calling undoManager.add() when Backspace is pressed - this did restore the characters I've deleted which is the wanted behavior, but for some reason it sent the cursor to the start of the current section written (or the start of the text if it started off blank). Obviously I want the cursor to be where it was when I wrote those characters (where they used to be before they were deleted)

To fix the cursor jump problem: I tried saving the selection Rng on backspace and restoring it on undo but that didn't work (the cursor kept jumping to the start of the section instead of staying), maybe the solution involves providing more data to the add() function?


Also, I can't currently upgrade TinyMCE so I would love some help that doesn't include upgrading.
Thank you!

check if this helps, you need to push text in stack according the docs https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/latest/apis/tinymce.undomanager/
